# SQL in BigQuery CASE WHEN with categorical variables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to redistribute my revenue depending on the platform source (PC, Web, Mobile) because I pay a different tax for any of those platforms in order to get my net revenue in Google BigQuery. This is a sample of my data:

[image]

I have tried to create a CASE WHEN depending on the values of the platform source but it is not working. The output is only zeros.

```
CASE WHEN ${platform_source} = 'Mobile' THEN ${revenue_raw} * 0.7
              WHEN ${platform_source} = 'Web' THEN ${revenue_raw} * 0.88
              WHEN ${platform_source} = 'Pc' THEN ${d1_iap_revenue_raw} * 0.88
              ELSE NULL END
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If none of the conditions match, as @Mr.Batra has mentioned, there is a possibility of the `Platform` column containing extra spaces. You can check the length of strings in the column using the [LENGTH](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#length) function. If the string lengths are not the expected values, the column has to be processed.

Comment: Hello. If my answer addressed your question, please consider upvoting and accepting it. If not, let me know so that the answer can be improved. Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If none of the conditions match, as @Mr.Batra has mentioned, there is a possibility of the `Platform` column containing extra spaces. If the string lengths are not the expected values, the column has to be processed.

To process the column and remove any trailing or leading spaces, use the [`TRIM`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#trim) function.

```
CASE WHEN TRIM(${platform_source}) = 'Mobile' THEN ${revenue_raw} * 0.7
     WHEN TRIM(${platform_source}) = 'Web' THEN ${revenue_raw} * 0.88
     WHEN TRIM(${platform_source}) = 'PC' THEN ${d1_iap_revenue_raw} * 0.88
ELSE NULL END
```

Answer (score 0):

String matching is case sensitive.

Try this

```sql
CASE WHEN ${platform_source} = 'Mobile' THEN ${revenue_raw} * 0.7
              WHEN ${platform_source} = 'Web' THEN ${revenue_raw} * 0.88
              WHEN ${platform_source} = 'PC' THEN ${d1_iap_revenue_raw} * 0.88
              ELSE NULL END
```

Comment: Tried it, but it is still returning zero... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you checked for leading and trailing spaces?